# How can one show a Kmeans solution is unique?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, optimization, algorithms

Suppose we are given a distribution P and a constant K. We wish to minimize the kmeans objective w.r.t centers ${C1,..Ck}$:

[image: Kmeans Objective]

What constraints on $P$ are known to imply that the optimal solution is unique (up to reordering of centers)?
Examples of ad hoc methods would also be appreciated.
In particular intereset to me are continuous distributions.

An example for one-dimensional $P(x)$ and $k=2$ with a unique optimal solution:

$P(X=1)=0.5$

$P(X=-1)=0.5$

The only optimal centers are $C1=1, C2=-1$

Comment: but that's the thing: in the absence of further constraints the optimal solution is not necessarely unique.

Comment: @user603 - I am looking for families of distributions, or constraints under which the solution is unique. I was hoping such conditions exist for P and K, similar to how we can say interesting things about convex problems.

Comment: Let me put it this way: unless $k=1$, your $W(c)$ is non convex in $c$. The final solution will depend on the starting points. Unless you choose the starting point deterministically you will always have convergence to random roots with some non-0 probability.

Comment: @user603 - Note that the question is algorithm independent. It is referring to global solutions of the given objective function. It is easy to come up with examples for P and k>1 where the solution is unique. I am interested in finding out what constraints are known to ensure a unique solution. (In particular for non-discrete P)

Comment: 'It is easy to come up with examples for P and k>1 where the solution is unique' can you add one such example to your question? I think it'll clarify what you mean.

Comment: @user603 - Please see the example I've added

Comment: What good is it to know if "the solution" (which usually will not be unique) is unique, given that the actual problem is NP-hard, so we use approximate solutions only anyway?

Comment: @leo: thanks for the example. Indeed, I wrote my comment assuming $p>1$ (e.g. that there is no natural ordering of the observations).

Answer (score 3):

K-means is a simplified version of Gaussian Mixture Models (GMM) in that it is equivalent to a GMM with all components having equal variance.  It is useful to think in terms of the variance because your sample distribution is going to have not only central tendency but variational tendency.  I am going to assume at this point that the GMM is appropriate for fitting to the data, that you are not fitting a GMM to non-GMM data.

If your sample data is extremely well behaved, such that the likelihood of a false classification is very low when the cluster centers are placed near the actual centers, then you can have well behaved EM convergence.  The plot of the AIC (or AICc) vs. iteration will tend to converge quickly toward a stable and low value.  If your sample is less well behaved then you can have a number of problematic phenomena including lack of convergence or cycling of the means between some number of center locations.  It is useful to think of [Cpk](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section1/pmc16.htm) when looking at the variations between clustered components because it is a robust measure of misclassification rate.  It is used in control charts and process control to indicate likely misclassification rates.

At this point it is very tempting to use some "diffusion-esqe" method in the algorithm to accomplish smoothing of the AIC plot to estimate the point of convergence.  Under-relaxation is simple to implement.  You use EM to compute the updated position of the means, but only move them some small distance toward the new position, then compute again.  This reduces the "noise" some but not entirely.  You will have a new dial, the "learning factor" or "relaxation factor".  This is EWMA on the position of the mean.

You can use bootstrap resampling within clusters to estimate the variation in the mean for the cluster between EM steps.  If your cluster center stays within the ranged indicated by the resampling for some amount of time then you could assume convergence.

This answer is entirely based on experience, not on theory, and that it gives algorithm directions instead of theoretical proof.  It is somewhat Ad-hoc, so I hope that it has value in that.

Comment: +1 I appreciate the interesting ideas and thoughtful discussion of them.

Comment: I would perform a K-means fit, slightly adjust it as a EM GMM fit, then use the analytic expressions to compute the Cpk for cluster membership.  If Cpk is above a good-enough threshold (x>1.3) then the chances of it not being a unique solution are low.  It is "unique-enough".

Answer (score 3):

First problem, the solution is not unique.

A simple exemple is $P(X=-1)=P(X=0)=P(X=1)= \frac{1}{3}$

This gives:

[image]

Depending on initial conditions. We encounter this problem when we have very particular symmetries. In practice this is very rare, almost impossible.

You may be mixing up this problem with a second one. The convergence of basic k-means  is granted to a local minimum of the cost function, not the global minimum. An exemple from Wikipedia:

[image]
You can adress this problem in many ways: starting near the optimal solution, randomizing the starting points... etc

While the uniqueness of the optimal solution is almost sure, you may end up with many local solutions.

Comment: thanks for the illustration. But as mentioned in the comments above, we are aware that without further constraints the solution is not guaranteed to be unique. These are the kinds of constraints the question asks about. Also, the question refers to global optima of the kmeans objective.